# How to delete temp files created by Archive Manager?

Tags: files, archive, cleanup

I used Archive Manager to extract files from an archive, but there wasn't enough free disk space. After the process crashed my disk remained full and I am unable to locate and delete what is filling up my hard drive. I cleaned up some disk space by moving some files to an external drive and then I attempted the same operation again. This time it succeeded, but again temporary files remained, clogging my hard drive. Where does this app store these files? I have been unable to find them in every way I have tried so far. I am also a complete newbie to Ubuntu (I use 14.10). Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: it's probably somewhere in `~/.cache`. What does `du -hd1 ~/.cache` say?

Comment: How did you extract those files?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to clean file-roller temporal folders with this command:

```
rm -r ~/.cache/.fr-*
```

The above command will delete all the file-roller temporary folders that can remain. **Be careful and copy/paste! A typo can be fatal for your data!**

The temporary folders of file-roller (it creates one for each archiver while contents are open) are stored in `/home/$USER/.cache/.fr-somerandomcharacters`.

Comment: @guntbert sorry, I wrote a fast reply from a tablet, now is updated.

Comment: They shouldn't be stored in `~/.cache`, unless it's a bug regression: [Launchpad.net: Bug 1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/file-roller/+bug/245716), [Launchpad.net: Bug 2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/file-roller/+bug/883628) and [Launchpad.net: Bug 3](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/file-roller/+bug/1186989)

Answer (score 1):

Temporary files are usually stored in `/tmp`, and that's the case even for `Archive Manager`. Anyway it's not a good practice to batch remove them, since running applications might be using the folder to store temporary files necessary to their current instance to run (as it's the case for `Archive Manager`), and removing them could break the current instance. So you better either remove the files manually or just reboot, which automatically clears the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you for all your answers. The files were not located in the temp or cache folders, so at the end I installed bleachbit and ran every possible cleanup option that I thought might help. At the end I parted with almost 9000 files and 5.5gb of data so I assume the files I was after are in that mix. Fortunately, the system is still runing fine after all that. Anyways, I appreciate everyone's help.